# Node Heroku Error – ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, express

In my development app, everything is great, but once deployed to Heroku, I get the following errors and my page won't load correctly.  Does anyone have any tips?

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING http://servant.co/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING http://servant.co/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING http://servant.co/lib/angular/angular.js
```

Comment: Here is the reason for the problem, it's in the 'compression' library https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/12 It's since been updated and now works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you close the `res` object with following like:

```
res.write(...); //here you write the response
res.end(); // <=== this is the problem, you should end the response
```